# Magento: Filters on bundled products

Tags: magento-1.7, layered-navigation

Is there any possiblity that i can filter on bundled products. I just can't make them active.
eg: I sell computers and people can choose between 3 (or more cases). Can that be filtered in a layered navigation???

I think so. But it won't appear on the front end what ever i do...

Thanks already

Answer (score 0):

My config

Bundle product
- simple product
- simple product
- simple product
- etc

The simple products has the filterable attribute.

Solution:
Add the filterable attributes to the bundle product and leave them empty. I'm surprised that this worked out. :?